# MS SQL Server view with conditional values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table A that can reference to itself to inherit some values from a parent. The reference is represented with ParentID. Parents have null values in ParentID.

| ID | ParentID | Field A | Field B | Field C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | ValueA1 | ValueB1 | ValueC1 |
| 2 | NULL | ValueA2 | ValueB2 | ValueC2 |
| 3 | 1 | null | ValueB3 | null |
| 4 | 1 | null | ValueB4 | null |
| 5 | 2 | ValueA5 | ValueB5 | null |
| 6 | NULL | ValueA6 | ValueB6 | ValueC6 |

and another table A_Inheritance to determine if a value from any field should be inherited from the parent:

| ID | A_ID | Inherits A | Inherits B | Inherits C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | True | False | true |
| 2 | 4 | True | False | true |
| 3 | 5 | False | False | true |

The first two rows in Table A are parents. The other 3 rows are children that inherit some values. The values to be inherited are specified in the table A_Inheritance.

Therefore the view should contain the following values:

| ID | ParentID | Field A | Field B | Field C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | ValueA1 | ValueB1 | ValueC1 |
| 2 | NULL | ValueA2 | ValueB2 | ValueC2 |
| 3 | 1 | ValueA1 | ValueB3 | ValueC1 |
| 4 | 1 | ValueA1 | ValueB4 | ValueC1 |
| 5 | 2 | ValueA5 | ValueB5 | ValueC2 |
| 6 | NULL | ValueA6 | ValueB6 | ValueC6 |

Is it possible to create a view like it in SQL Server? I am trying to write some selects but I am struggling when I write to use the IF statement.

Any help will be appreciated.

Kind regards

Comment: Can the inheritance be nested, are there recursive nested levels of inheritance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have one level of inheritance, then this is [a simple `LEFT JOIN` query](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c6fe11b1e0ff4ad4c076fd973c1df33a), as mentioned in [the comments by @lptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70280808/ms-sql-server-view-with-conditional-values#comment124238805_70280808).

Assuming you actually have nested (recursive) levels of inheritance, you would need a recursive CTE

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
      A.Id,
      A.ParentId,
      TopParent = A.ParentId,
      A.fieldA,
      A.fieldB,
      A.fieldC,
      ai.InheritsA,
      ai.InheritsB,
      ai.InheritsC
    FROM A  -- get bottom children
    LEFT JOIN A_inheritance ai ON ai.A_Id = A.Id  -- and their inheritance rules
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT
      cte.Id,
      cte.ParentId,
      A.ParentId,
      CASE WHEN cte.InheritsA = 'True' THEN ISNULL(cte.fieldA, A.fieldA) ELSE cte.fieldA END,
      CASE WHEN cte.InheritsB = 'True' THEN ISNULL(cte.fieldB, A.fieldB) ELSE cte.fieldB END,
      CASE WHEN cte.InheritsC = 'True' THEN ISNULL(cte.fieldC, A.fieldC) ELSE cte.fieldC END,
      cte.InheritsA,
      cte.InheritsB,
      cte.InheritsC
    FROM A
    JOIN cte ON cte.TopParent = A.Id  -- join on all parents
)
SELECT
  A.Id,
  A.ParentId,
  A.fieldA,
  A.fieldB,
  A.fieldC
FROM cte A
WHERE A.TopParent IS NULL  -- only rows where we have reached the top
ORDER BY
  A.Id;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=06648c2fa7adfdd4e6cf25fa85a8df45)